# Ghost attachments in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, replication, attachment

I'm having an issue with CouchDB 1.1.0. I created a Database in my laptop and replicated it to my server. Then, I added attachments to my local database and replicated them to the remote database.

On the second replication, it seems an error appeared. Attachments were uploaded correctly, but I was unable to them attached on the docs.

If I check the database size, they are here. But I have no way get them and no way to delete them. (Cleaning the database don't remove them).

When replicating from the remote to another DB, I still have the "ghost attachments" replicated.

Does anyone has any idea on this? How could I delete this attachments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you have a document *conflict*.

Unlike a military conflict or a ethical conflict, a [CouchDB conflict](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html) is normal and useful, usually occurring after replication. (Conflicts are somewhat similar to *branches* in Git, Mercurial, or Bzr.)

During replication, CouchDB sometimes receives an alternative versions of the same document. In this situation, instead replacing one revision with the other, CouchDB stores both. Unfortunately, when you query CouchDB to fetch that document, it must decide which one to send; and basically it just picks one revision and sends that. Using a normal `GET /db/doc_id` query you would never even realize that a "conflicting" (alternative) revision is hiding in the database somewhere.

The link above shows how to find and resolve conflicts (when you delete the unwanted revision, the remaining revision will be visible.) The crucial example is the view to find conflicts:

```
function(doc) {
  // Map function in a CouchDB view to find conflicts.
  if(doc._conflicts) {
    emit(doc._conflicts, null);
  }
}
```

If you query that view, I think you will see some conflicts. If the view returns 0 rows, then this is not the problem at all and we'll have to keep thinking about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I had conflicts. Thanks Jason

If someone need more information about conflicts, just

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html

I just created a small Node scripts to get all conflicts via a view and delete them.